Why does it fail to detect WAVE or RIFF?
I'm trying to load a wav file into a C++ app
I Keep getting the program to print Invalid Wav File with exit code 5. This means the program thinks the chunkID didn't match RIFF or the format didn't match WAVE.
how can i fix it?
this is what i currently have in my code
the WAV_Decoder class is responsible for loading in the file then processing
the WAV header and then storing the file into an array that i can later on use in the application but the problem is the WAV file is getting processed as an invalid format
even though the WAV file is not corrupted and plays smoothly on my device using media player
WAV_Decoder.hpp
#pragma once

struct WAV_Header
{
    char chunkID[4];
    uint32_t chunkSize;
    char format[4];
    char subchunk1ID[4];
    uint32_t subchunk1Size;
    uint16_t audioFormat;
    uint16_t numChannels;
    uint32_t sampleRate;
    uint32_t byteRate;
    uint16_t blockAlign;
    uint16_t bitsPerSample;
    char subchunk2ID[4];
    uint32_t subchunk2Size;
};

class WAV_Decoder
{
private:

public:
    WAV_Decoder() = default;
    void LoadWav(std::string filename);

    std::vector<char>& getAudioBuffer();
private:
    std::vector<char> audio_buffer;
    WAV_Header wav_header;
};

WAV_Decoder.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

#include "TTS/WAV_Decoder.hpp"


void WAV_Decoder::LoadWav(std::string filename)
{
    std::ifstream file(filename.c_str(), std::ios::binary);
    if (!file)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to load WAV file :*(\n";
        exit(4);
    }


    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&wav_header), sizeof(wav_header));

    std::cout << std::string(wav_header.chunkID, 4) << '\n';

    if (std::string(wav_header.chunkID, 4) != "RIFF" || std::string(wav_header.format, 4) != "WAVE")
    {
        std::cerr << "Invalid Wav File\n";
        exit(5);
    }

    audio_buffer.resize(wav_header.subchunk2Size);
    file.read(audio_buffer.data(), wav_header.subchunk2Size);

    file.close();
}

std::vector<char>& WAV_Decoder::getAudioBuffer()
{
    return audio_buffer;
}

main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

#include "TTS/WAV_Decoder.hpp"

int main()
{
    WAV_Decoder test_decoder;
    std::cout << test_decoder.getAudioBuffer().size();

    test_decoder.LoadWav("D:/Absolute/File/Path/out.wav");

    std::cout << test_decoder.getAudioBuffer().size();

    return 0;
}


Maybe the file is not a valid wav file. Maybe whatever library you are using has a bug. Maybe it's some type of user error.

This code is not C language.  The C language doesn't have std::cout.  Are you mixing languages?  If not, please remove unused tags.

Set a breakpoint on if (std::string(wav_header.chunkID, 4) != "RIFF" || std::string(wav_header.format, 4) != "WAVE") and see what value is in wav_header.chunkID and wav_header.format

Consider changing your error message to actually describe what is wrong.

Unrelated: std::string(wav_header.chunkID, 4) == "RIFF" would be cheaper with std::string_view(wav_header.chunkID, sizeof wav_header.chunkID) == "RIFF" or just a memcmp

Perhaps show us (in a hexdump) the first 352 bytes of the file you are trying to read in?

how can i fix it? It may not be fixable. @jxh presented a very good idea. That should tell us if the file is not in the format that this reader expects.

I thought this was a boolean logic error, but I think it is probably related to endianess.

download *nix file, FFMPEG or Exifinfo and they'll tell you the actual format of the file immediately. But why not have a hex editor when working with binary files?
